# External Standalone QGIS Application with Default Toolbars?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to develop a standalone application and add the default digitizing and advanced digitizing tools in QGIS as-is on my application through PyQGIS.

Is it similar the way you add the navigation tools (like Pan Zoom In and Out..)?

What do you suggest?

I am a beginner to PyQGIS.

Comment: Please form one single question and include what you have tried. What type of answer you are looking for. j(i.e. just a little help or write it for me please)

Comment: Ok Brad. Just a beginner here. I have set up Eclipse and I am developing a QGIS external application. I will want most of the QGIS as they are, while I will have to add my own. I was able to add the navigation tools using MapTool from QGIS. I was wondering if it is possible to add the split feature, add feature, node tools from QGIS digitizing toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to follow another approach. You can customize the QGIS-GUI and even create a QGIS installer to distribute your customized QGIS. The QGIS-GUI customization was well explained by Tim Sutton in http://linfiniti.com/2011/07/customizing-the-qgis-ui/ You would just need to enable the tools you want (i.e., digitizing and advanced digitizing tools) and disable the rest.

[image: Customized QGIS, by Tim Sutton.]

If you go for Python you would need to replicate (develop) each tool's behavior, because not all QGIS tools are provided as PyQGIS classes, so it would require a lot of effort and time from your side.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to develop a work flow based QGIS application, and for that I will require an external application. I think *replicating the tool's behavior* from C++ to Python is the only choice I can think of.